# The Doctrine make a not correct diff for an entity with ENUM type

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I did a special `ENUM` type for property **type** of entity **Command** by [cookbook](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/mysql-enums.html).

**The property looks like this one:**

```php
    /**
     * @var CommandType
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="command_type")
     */
    protected $type;
```

**This snippet describe new type for doctrine:**

```php
final class CommandTypeType extends EnumerableType
{
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'VARCHAR(30)';
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return 'command_type';
    }

    protected function getClassName(): string
    {
        return CommandType::class;
    }
}
```

After first run command `/bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` for an entity, I get the migration and it looks correct

```php
final class Version2020 072720500 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        $this->addSql("CREATE TABLE commands (
                id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
                name VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
                command VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
                type varchar(30) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY(id)
        ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE `UTF8_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB");
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE commands');
    }
}
```

Next step is run command `/bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` and it works correct, table created.

Then I run command `/bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` one more time and get new migration

```php
final class Version20200727205035 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE commands CHANGE type type VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE commands CHANGE type type VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`');
    }
}
```

**I don't know** why the second diff generated this strange migration.
**What I did wrong?**

- Symfony 4.4
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 3.0.1
- doctrine/migrations                 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine needs a comment to be added to the column to detect that the custom type has been applied to the column.

Check the `requiresSQLCommentHint` method is implemented and returns true or add it to your custom type.

```php
final class CommandTypeType extends EnumerableType
{
    ...

    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You should see a comment to be added to your column on the next migration and nothing more.

Comment: I added a new property to ENUM and ran `doctrine:migrations:diff`, but the new change did not appear, maybe do you know how fix it?

Comment: From the ORM point of view nothing had changed, you have to add it manually generating a migration. You can always try to change a column property (length for example) to make doctrine think that something has been changed, but I’m not sure it’ll work.